# MongoDB find by origin and destination

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection for shipping trucks which have origin coordinates and destination coordinates as well as a radius value for each to determine how far out of the way a truck is willing to drive to pick up/drop off packages. Like so...

```
origin:{ 
 location { coordinates:[ 40.7128, 74.006 ] }, 
 radius:25 
}
destination:{ 
 location { coordinates:[ 34.0522, 118.2437 ] }, 
 radius:25 
}
```

The trouble is I don't think MongoDB will let me have two 2dsphere Indexes.

**How can I query the collection for trucks which have an origin and destination which are within their radius distances to a given set of points?**

Comment: I would investigate using $expr for one of the conditions (the less selective one).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with based on the [haversine formula](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

```
.aggregate({
    $addFields: { distanceToDestination: {
      $multiply: [6371000,
        { $multiply: [2, { $atan2: [{ $sqrt: { $add: [
          { $multiply: [
            { $sin: { $divide: [{ $degreesToRadians: { $subtract: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['$destination.location.coordinates', 1] }, Number(destinationLatitude)] } }, 2] } },
            { $sin: { $divide: [{ $degreesToRadians: { $subtract: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['$destination.location.coordinates', 1] }, Number(destinationLatitude)] } }, 2] } },
          ] },
          { $multiply: [
            { $cos: { $degreesToRadians: Number(destinationLatitude) } },
            { $cos: { $degreesToRadians: { $arrayElemAt: ['$destination.location.coordinates', 1] } } },
            { $sin: { $divide: [{ $degreesToRadians: { $subtract: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['$destination.location.coordinates', 0] }, Number(destinationLongitude)] } }, 2] } },
            { $sin: { $divide: [{ $degreesToRadians: { $subtract: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['$destination.location.coordinates', 0] }, Number(destinationLongitude)] } }, 2] } },
          ] },
        ] } },
        { $sqrt: { $subtract: [1, { $add: [
          { $multiply: [
            { $sin: { $divide: [{ $degreesToRadians: { $subtract: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['$destination.location.coordinates', 1] }, Number(destinationLatitude)] } }, 2] } },
            { $sin: { $divide: [{ $degreesToRadians: { $subtract: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['$destination.location.coordinates', 1] }, Number(destinationLatitude)] } }, 2] } },
          ] },
          { $multiply: [
            { $cos: { $degreesToRadians: Number(destinationLatitude) } },
            { $cos: { $degreesToRadians: { $arrayElemAt: ['$destination.location.coordinates', 1] } } },
            { $sin: { $divide: [{ $degreesToRadians: { $subtract: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['$destination.location.coordinates', 0] }, Number(destinationLongitude)] } }, 2] } },
            { $sin: { $divide: [{ $degreesToRadians: { $subtract: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['$destination.location.coordinates', 0] }, Number(destinationLongitude)] } }, 2] } },
          ] },
        ] }] } }] }] },
      ],
    } },
  },{ $match: { $expr: { $lt: ['$distanceToDestination', { $multiply: ['$destination.radius', 1609] }] } } })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I ended up using [$geowithin query with $centersphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/#op._S_centerSphere) which does not require 2d/2dsphere index.

```
//collection example
{
  "origin": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-119.158323, 34.177169]//<longitude>, <latitude>              
  },                
  "destination": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-117.274471, 32.832215]//<longitude>, <latitude>              
  }
}
```

Note: I used [GeoJSON objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-geojson) here in my example for storing coordinates. $centersphere also supports legacy coordinate pairs according to [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/#op._S_centerSphere).

```js
const originCoords: [-119.159392, 34.164958];//query params
const destCoords:  [-117.221505, 32.873788 ];//query params
const distInRadians = 25 / 3963.2;//converts the distance from miles to radians by dividing by the approximate equatorial radius of the earth

collection.find({
  origin: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ originCoords, distInRadians ] } },
  destination:{ $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ destCoords, distInRadians ] } }
}).toArray(function(err,results) {
   //processing query results here
});
```

Hope this answer will be helpful!